# SagePay repeat payments in a batch

Tags: api, opayo

Does anyone know if it is possible to perform SagePay repeat payments in a batch, either using MySagePay or via an API call?

i.e. each month charge a list of people X amount of money

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a spreadsheet / bunch of macros to do this.

I've coded an example which you can download (completely unsupported). I've loaded it with a test account and some transactions so you can give it a try - if you want to try it on your own test account, just change the credentials in StaticData workbook and update the RelatedVendorTxCodes in Transactions to match those you want to repeat.

https://www.sagepaylabs.com/RepeatTransaction.xlsm